# How to $lookup with case sensitive values localField, in mongoDB V6

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have two collection and need to performs a left outer join on it.
With `$lookup` is works good but the problem is that the collections come from some API where the value of `localField` is in lower case and `foreignField` is in upper case.

How to use `$lookup` to ignore or to lowerCase the value(s)?
I try something but I have no chance. I found a solution but is for a older version of mongodb. If you have any experience please help :)

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'mycollection',
      localField: 'symbol',
      foreignField: 'index_id',
      as: 'foo',
    },
  },
]);
```

Comment: Prepend an $addFields stage to generate the upper case version of the string to be used in the localField argument for the subsequent $lookup stage

Comment: I'm a new bee to mongoDB and I dont know how to do it. Please can you show me in a concrete example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do an [`$addFields`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) stage before the lookup to create an uppercase field and  then lookup on that field. This is similar to a `$project` stage that explicitly specifies all existing fields in the input documents and adds the new fields.

for two dummy collections that look like this

```js
db={
  "stocks": [
    {symbol: "aapl",name: "Apple Inc."},
    {symbol: "googl",name: "Alphabet Inc."},
    {symbol: "amzn",name: "Amazon.com, Inc."}
  ],
  "prices": [
    {index_id: "AAPL",price: 145.44},
    {index_id: "GOOGL",price: 2672.75},
    {index_id: "MSFT",price: 237.58}
  ]
}
```

```js
db.stocks.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      symbol_upper: {
        $toUpper: "$symbol"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "prices",
      localField: "symbol_upper",
      foreignField: "index_id",
      as: "foo"
    }
  }
])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cjvifo-ICTq)

if you want to remove the added field from the output just add a `$project` stage like

```js
  {
    $project: {
      symbol_upper: 0
    }
  }
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/D0NWoGlZBcy)

Comment: I run in the next dilemma :) Now I fetch and save the JSON data from an API provider into two collections on MongoDB Atlas. The question is how to get the two collection to run the lookup code in nodeJs and than save it back in a new collection on MongoDB server. Any answer will be very appreciated.

Comment: This is the code I use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980886/how-to-save-an-json-file-from-an-api-uri-directly-to-a-mongodb-collection-in-nod/75981190#75981190

Comment: I'm not sure if  const myCollection1 = db.collection("stocks").find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {.....} is the right one