# How to save an JSON file from an API URI directly to a mongoDB collection in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, rest, axios

I'm pretty new to MERN and I wonder if it possible at all. If you have any experience please help :)

Here my naive code:

**1. Create axios client**

```
const api = axios.create({
  method: 'GET',
  baseURL: 'https://api.someAPI.com',
  headers: {
    'API_KEY': process.env.API_KEY,
    Accept: 'application/json',
  },
});
```

**2. Get JSON and save it to a new collection on MongoDB**

```
function getAPI_AndSaveToDB() {
  api('/api/v3/exactURI')
    .then((value) => res.json(value.data))
    .then(dbo.createCollection("myCollection")
    .then(myCollection.insertMany(value));
}
```

Comment: yes it is possible. even more readable/easier with async await

Comment: @cmgchess, do you have a working code please? (async await is pretty clear for me but I dont know how to implement in this example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Single document

This is an example using Axios for the request, and the official MongoDB driver. You can learn from it and adapt to your needs: maybe you want to consider using an ORM like Mongoose as well, depending on your project.

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

async function fetchDataAndSaveToMongoDB() {
  // Fetch the JSON data from a URL
  const { data } = await axios.get('https://example.com/data.json');

  // Connect to MongoDB
  const client = new MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017');
  await client.connect();

  try {
    // Select the database and collection
    const db = client.db('mydb');
    const collection = db.collection('mycollection');

    // Insert the JSON data into the collection
    const result = await collection.insertOne(data);
    console.log(`${result.insertedCount} document(s) inserted`);
  } finally {
    // Close the MongoDB connection
    await client.close();
  }
}

fetchDataAndSaveToMongoDB();
```

Note that you will need to install the axios and mongodb modules in your Node.js project for this code to work. You can do so by running the following command in your project directory:

```bash
$ npm install axios mongodb
```

#### Multiple documents

If the requested file is an array, you can replace the [`insertOne`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertOne/) with [`insertMany`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/) method of the MongoDB driver to insert each element of the array as a separate document in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE** For the moment I follow the instuctions from @Ezequias Dinella (Thank you very much!) and have this code witch is not ready but a step forward.

```
const axios = require('axios');
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

async function fetchAndSaveDataToDB() {
  // Fetch the JSON data from a API URL
  const api = axios.create({
    method: 'GET',
    baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL,
    headers: {
      API_KEY: process.env.API_KEY,
      Accept: 'application/json',
    },
  });
  const { data } = await api.get(process.env.URI);

  // Insert the JSON data into the collection
  await mongoClient.connect();
  try {
    const database = mongoClient.db('myDB');
    //drop old collection
    const oldCollection = 'collection_12';
    const isDropped = database.collection(oldCollection).drop();
    if (!isDropped) {
      console.log(`ERROR:: ${oldCollection} not dropped`);
    } else {
      console.log(`${oldCollection} successfully dropped`);
    }

    // Insert the JSON data into a new collection
    const collectionName = 'collection_14';
    const theNewCollection = database.collection(collectionName);
    const options = { ordered: true }; //prevents insert docs if one fails
    const result = await theNewCollection.insertMany(data, options);
    console.log(
      `${result.insertedCount} documents in ${collectionName} successfully inserted`
    );
  } finally {
    await mongoClient.close();
  }
}

fetchAndSaveDataToDB().catch(console.dir);
```